# PHP 5.5 resources

Tags: php

Good morning. I am relatively new to PHP, though I did finish a 10 week night course a couple of months ago. Unfortunately, I am constantly finding that a lot of the methods we were taught and the functions we used are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 release.

I have searched online and in book shops, and have also had no luck on Lynda.com, trying to find a guide to learning PHP 5.5.

The trouble is, I am not at an advanced level, therefore I still really need pretty much a beginners guide, but I want this guide to be consistent with 5.5 not 5.4. I am also keen to learn more about PDO's as I am beginning to see their flexibility.

Does anybody know of any online resources or books that can be purchased that may suit my needs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://www.phptherightway.com/ is the best recent resource I can think of